# Building SCORM 2004 3rd Edition SCOs

Tags: scorm, scorm2004

I need an application for building SCOs based on SCORM 2004 3rd edition. I'm going to use Run-Time Environment data model elements (cmi.xxx) easily and without having to JavaScript coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this website: http://www.naseelco.com. They have what you are looking for (Elearing Authoring Tool). They also have other tools for testing and debugging SCORM courses.